# how to set the quartz worker threads get created whenever its required

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am setting

> org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleTreadPool
>
> org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 100

if i use this quarts will create a **100 worker** threads and all are in waiting state,

i don't want this, it suppose to create when ever required. how to achieve that.

Comment: @Prasad V S Your suggested edit "org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5" should rather be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'maximum pool size' property in Quartz. The only properties you have are described here :

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigThreadPool

Quartz uses a simple implementation of threads pool. If you want a better one that initializes new threads when it is needed and release resources, you'll need to find another thread pool implementation or to implement your own thread pool and use the `org.quartz.threadPool.class` property.